# Constant c in BIG O NOTATION

Tags: big-o

Suppose f(n) is runtime of algorithm.

According to function definition of `O(n)`, if `f(n)<=c*g(n)` then `f(n)=O(g(n))` where `n0<=n`.

What is the range of values constant c can take?

Answer (score 5):

By definition (e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)), any positive number, as long as it's constant.

For instance, `n^2` is *not* in `O(n)` because there is no positive number `c` such that `n^2 = cn` for all `n`; that equality is trivially solved to `c = n`, but by definition `n` is not a constant.

Comment: This did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It can be any positive number. If it is 0  you do nothing, if it is negative you break something.

To speak simply c is an constant consisted of two halves:

1. Algorithm half. For example your algo has to iterate 5 times through entire input collection. So constant will be 5. If your another algorithm iterates 3 times. Then constant will be 3, but both of your algo will have complexity O(n).
2. Hardware half. It is time needed to compute one operation on your pc. If you start app implementing your algo upon the same collection on Pentium 1 and on modern Xeon it is obvious that Xeon will compute the result much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`C` can be anything (above zero, obviously). Doesn't matter: `0.1` or `1` or `1.000.000`. The only thing: it **must be constant** - i.e. may be defined once and for all. It must not depend from `n`. Of course, `C` will affect total algorithm performance - but the purpose of big-O is to estimate performance, not calculate it precisely (well, that goes from definition)

Comment: No. No and no. `C` isn't related to `n`. You can not say anything about `C ? n` (and put `>`, `<` or anything instead of `?`). `n` is __dynamic__ while `C` is __static__. For example, you have `O = O(2n^2)` Then for `n=1` you'll get `"C>n"` but for `n=2` you'll get `"C<n"` (expressions in quotes intended to show how senseless is that comparison)

Comment: so the value of c is anything greater than 0,such that for all n0<=n,
f(n)<=c*g(n)  holds?

Comment: Not sure why are you trying to compare `C` with something. It's just __is__. And it's constant

Answer (score 1):

While `c` is independent of `n`, one is allowed to exclude some special cases for small `n` and determine the `c` only for `n ≥ n0`.

For instance,

```
n ≤ n^2 for n ≥ 1
```

but also

```
n ≤ 0.01*n^2 for n ≥ 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Any range.

`c` being a constance means that it does not depend on the size `n` of the problem. Whenever the value of `n` changes, `c` remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `f(n)=n+1` and `g(n)=n^2`

We try to prove that `f(n)=O(g(n))`

For n=1,f(n)=2,g(n)=1   `f(n)<=c * g(n)` if c=2 and now c>n

For n=2,f(n)=3,g(n)=4    `f(n)<=c * g(n)` if c=1 and now c< n

So comparison between c and n is senseless.
**NOTE**: c is a constant (its value can never change)

So we can say,`f(n)=O(g(n)` for `n>=1` if `c=2`

But           `f(n)=O(g(n)` for `n>=2` if `c=1`